# Adding/creating data to empty dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I created an empty dataframe with 3 columns and then attempted to add values to individual columns row by row and i get an error that I can't resolve. I have about 300 entries that I've all hardcoded like the set below, so I'd like for them all to work but the code won't even work for one row of data.

```
DF<- data.frame(Code=character(),Value=integer(),Period=character(),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
DF$Code[1]<-'Code_A'
DF$Value[1]<-Input_Data$Value[Input_Data$Code=='Code_A']
DF$Period<-paste('Quarter1')

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Unique_Cell_Code", value = "B3283") : 
  replacement has 1 row, data has 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
DF[1,] <- c('Code_A', Input_Data$Value[Input_Data$Code=='Code_A'], paste('Quarter1'))
```

Comment: Thanks. My code currently defines objects as Code[1]<-'Code_A' and Value[1]<-Input_Data$Value[Input_Data$Code=='Code_A']. This is repeated for 300 rows. After defining these is when I'd like them to become values in column Code and Value. How do I do that in one go as opposed to copying your suggestion 300 times

Comment: @oivemaria so after creating your arrays `Code` and `Value`, you can create your `data frame` with the following code: `DF <- data.frame("Code" = Code, "Value" = Value)`

Comment: hopefully I understood correct your question, if not please consider editing your question.